# Oracle XE 18c, on every connect attempt, Oracle listener OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener stops, and I am unable to connect to any connection

Tags: oracle, listener

For the purpose of learning, I have installed **Oracle 18c XE v18.4.0.0** and **Oracle SQL Developer v21.4.2**.
I have no previous experience with Oracle database.
Command **LSNRCTL stat** seems to show correct results:

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 02-MAR-2022 20:15:29

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MAJAPC)(PORT=1521)))  
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                02-MAR-2022 19:49:32
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 26 min. 1 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oracle18\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oracle18\diag\tnslsnr\MAJAPC\listener\alert\log.xml

Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MAJAPC)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my
_wallet_directory=C:\ORACLE18\admin\XE\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "3bcb8ed4ef24494d93ec4d9b754310d2" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xepdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I am trying to connect to **XEPDB1** Plugin database by using sqlplus command:
**sqlplus system/oracle@192.168.1.102:1521/XEPDB1** (192.168.1.102 is my local IP)
but everytime I tried so, service **OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener** (and listener also) stops.
Responce to connection command after few minutes is: **ERROR: ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed**.
Then I start listener again manually and try again to connect to XEPDB1 but the same thing happen again.

**sqlplus system/oracle** command do a login to Oracle without any problem.

Files **listener.ora** and **tnsnames.ora** are not modified after fresh installation of Oracle 18c XE.

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle18\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle18\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\oracle18\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MAJAPC)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle18\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MAJAPC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MAJAPC)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

I am completely new to the Oracle database, and don't know which log items could show me what is the problem. That is why I am posting this issue to much more experienced people. Instructor ask us to install 18c XE because of easier setup than 21c XE. Beside this, versions greater than 18c are not supported on Windows 7.
Here are trace and alert logs from listener :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14mFzW0UgX5OVT75PE7Wxb7DZ2wce8wgl/view?usp=sharing
Much appreciate if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have hit a bug for sure.

`DDE was called in a 'No Invocation Mode'` with a stack trace.

It is hard to suggest an easy way forward.

I suggest you uninstall the 18c XE and rather go with Oracle VirtualBox and fire up one of Oracle's linux boxes where Oracle Database is present.

Another option is to run your Autonomous Oracle Database in Oracle Cloud. It is free forever. This is my preferred option these days.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks @Bjarte Brandt.
As you were saying, if I have hit a bug, then I can't do anything to solve it on my side. Right?
So I have to give up from Oracle XE 18c.
I will check my luck with older Oracle XE 11g

Comment: You are correct; the XE versions have no support options.